# What is "reference checking"?

Tags: publications, journals, paper-submission

I recently submitted a manuscript to the Indian journal of pure and applied mathematics. The submission was successful and the manuscript is under review (As per the shown status). But beside there a option "View reference checking results", and the following is shown there?
I don't know what does that mean?
Does that mean my manuscript cannot be published?

[image]

Comment: I wouldn't worry about this. References are usually checked carefully during preparation of proofs, i.e., after your manuscript has been accepted and passed to the production department. (Could the journal maybe expect you to upload a LaTeX or word file? It's rather unusual that a PDF is accepted.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They just check whether your references are correct. For example, did you get the volume right or did you spell the authors correctly.

Answer (score 2):

When submitting an article for publication, it is very important to check the requirements for submission.

In this case, it appears that you have submitted a file in .pdf format, which is not supported by the reference checking system of the journal. In the diagram in [this canonical journal workflow answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/55666/43873), you are probably stuck in the "Initial Check" phase and your submission process cannot proceed without further action from you.

You should probably:

1. Go back and look at the submission instructions again. If they specify that .docx or another format is required, you will need to save your article in a supported format and resubmit it.
2. For specific questions that are not answered by the submission instructions, there should be a link to contact the journal and/or the editor.